# How to change a SolidColorBrush resource's colour at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I change a colour in a resource dictionary being used in another resource dictionary at runtime?

Here's my setup:

**Colours.xaml:**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="themeColour" Color="#16A8EC"/>
```

**Styles.xaml:**

```
<Style x:Key="titleBar" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource themeColour}"/>
</Style>
```

**Window.xaml**

```
.....
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="res/Styles.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="res/Colours.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
.....

<Grid Style="{DynamicResource titleBar}"></Grid>
```

**Code behind:**

```
Application.Current.Resources["themeColour"] = new SolidColorBrush(newColour);
```

When the code runs the colour of the grid doesn't change. I don't think Application.Current.Resources["themeColour"] is referring to my solidcolorbrush resource as when if I try to access it before assigning it a new colour, I get a null object reference exception.

So, how should I access the resource "themeColour"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to your code to work, `ResourceDictionary` must be in a file `App.xaml` where `ResourceDictionary` should be:

`App.xaml`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary/StyleDictionary.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary/ColorDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

`Code-behind`

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush MyBrush = Brushes.Black;

    Application.Current.Resources["themeColour"] = MyBrush;
}
```

**Why is it better to use App.xaml**

- correctly all styles and resource dictionaries stored in this file because it was created specifically for this - to all application resources were available from one place. It can also affect application performance in a good way.
- there have been cases where a *StaticResource* has been used successfully, but not *DynamicResource* (resources are placed in the Window.Resources). But after moving the resource in `App.xaml`, everything started to work.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! It did seem a bit weird that I had to declare resources in every single window...putting them in app.xaml is a lot more convenient.

Answer (score 4):

It's because your resources are available in `Window` and not in `Application`. Try this in Window.xaml.cs:

```
this.Resources["themeColour"] = new SolidColorBrush(newColour);
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing as Anatoily said though