# Trying to apply SolidColorBrush resource to HeaderedContentControl BorderBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, solidcolorbrush

I'd like to link a SolidColorBrush from my Window to Another SolidColorBrush in My dictionary. I didn't find something like this , and may be it's not possible ...

here is the code in my "ResourceDictionary.xaml"

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushBlueTransparent" Color="#33006D8F"/>
```

And in my windows i want a link to this resource like this :

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlColor" Color="{Binding Source={DynamicResource BrushEvasanOrange}}"/>
```

For now, this code don't work ...

I want to use this link because i want to use this resource in my page in a multiple "" and if the color had to be change in the futur it could be easy to change with this way.

The Brush resource is used like this:

```
<HeaderedContentControl 
    x:Name="_demandeur" 
    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BrushEncadre}" 
    BorderThickness="1" 
    Padding="10" 
    Margin="0,20,0,0" 
    Header="{x:Static p:Resources.EV_Demandeur}"
    >
    <WrapPanel 
        Margin="0" 
        Orientation="Horizontal" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        >
        <TextBlock 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            FontWeight="Normal" 
            Text="text"
            />
    </WrapPanel>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

Comment: Your code wont work. Why not just embed the dictionary into your app.xaml as a merged dictionary. Then all the resources in the dictionary are global to your app and you can reference them from any other .xaml (window,page,usercontrol)

Comment: Define the color as a resource: `<Color x:Key="MyBlue">#33006D8F</Color>` then use it for both brushes: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushBlueTransparent" Color="{StaticResource MyBlue}"/>`

Comment: @jure :Thnaks for your answer, but In fact My "ResourceDictionary.xaml" is already a Merged Dictionnary that could be used in every xaml. I just want to use in a UserControl a link to another color for a lot of "HeaderedContentControl" for one thing, if i had to change the color of all this "HeaderedContentControl", i willl be easy to change this link.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: thank for your answer but it don't work in my solution. I use your sample of code for a "HeaderedContentControl/BorderBrush", and there no color in the view ... It was a good idea, so may be i'd made a mistake or in this case in can't work ^^

Comment: @StefG can you post what you tried? What didn't work about it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett, here is what i tried :
In my "ResourceDictionary.xaml" i've got that 
`<Color x:Key="BrushEvasanOrangeColor" >#FFEF7D00</Color>`
And in my window.xaml
-- ResourcePart --
`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushEncadre" Color="{StaticResource BrushEvasanOrangeColor}"/>`

Comment: Are you saying you put the word "`code`" in your resource dictionary, or is that a typo? Please paste the whole resource dictionary into your post. And please tell me exactly what you mean when you say it doesn't work. Color wrong in UI? Runtime exception? Compiler error? Sinkhole in your back yard? Interdimensional yacht race? Things can fail in so many ways, that's what makes life so much fun!

Comment: @EdPlunkett  -- ContentControl --
`<HeaderedContentControl x:Name="_demandeur" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BrushEncadre}" BorderThickness="1" Padding="10" Margin="0,20,0,0" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.EV_Demandeur}">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                        <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal" Text="text"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
            </HeaderedContentControl>`

Comment: If you refuse to give me the information I ask for, I can't help you. Good luck.

Comment: There were no error during compiling, ( or may be i don't catch enough ), and this code will change the border of my ContentControl. When i try to use the code i post in the previous comment, there were no color in my page. I can't post all my ResourceDictionary because it take 5000 lines ..

Comment: In your XAML file where the HeaderedContentControl is located, are you able to access any resources that are defined in the ResourceDictionary? Are you merging it into `Application.Resources` in App.xaml?

Comment: Bit of a guess, but this may be your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21264749/424129

Comment: @EdPlunkett, my  HeaderedContentControl is in the main grid of the window, and it use a template, this template is define in the resource of this window, not in  my App.xaml

Comment: @EdPlunkett, my ResourceDictionary.xaml is declared in App.xaml

Comment: What happens when you use StaticResource instead: `<HeaderedContentControl x:Name="_demandeur" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushEncadre}" ...`? What happens if you define your `BrushEncadre` with a literal color instead of the resource, like `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushEncadre" Color="Red"/>`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett, Thanks for your help, i'm gonna try this

Comment: I tried like your ask me, and it doesn't work .. but i made another test, i used this resource in textblok to affect the foreground and it work. I try with my HeaderedContentControl without Style, to affect foreground or backgroud like this, and it don't work too .. may be with HeaderedControl there is differents issues. thanks again for your help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is that `HeaderedContentControl` ignores its `BorderBrush` property. There are two ways to fix this: One is to replace the `HeaderedContentControl`'s `Template` with one that displays a border around the content, but that's a lot of trouble. Another is to use a subclass of `HeaderedContentControl` which already has a template that does you want (we'll get to that last).

One very simple option is to simply put a `Border` around the control, and move the `Margin` to the `Border` as well, so the orange border line will be inside the margin. This isn't the right answer in your specific case, but it's a good general answer to "how do I put a border around things in XAML?"

```
<Border
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushEncadre}" 
    BorderThickness="1" 
    Margin="0,20,0,0" 
    >
    <HeaderedContentControl 
        x:Name="_demandeur" 
        Padding="10" 
        Header="{x:Static p:Resources.EV_Demandeur}"
        >
        <WrapPanel 
            Margin="0" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <TextBlock 
                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                FontWeight="Normal" 
                Text="text"
                />
        </WrapPanel>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
</Border>
```

But I'm wondering if `HeaderedContentControl` is really what you want here. `HeaderedContentControl` is a base class for a variety of controls which display content with a header. The subclasses are much more commonly used, and I have a feeling that what you really want here is `GroupBox`, which is one of those subclasses. You'd use it just the way you were using `HeaderedContentControl`:

```
<GroupBox 
    x:Name="_demandeur" 
    Padding="10" 
    Margin="0,20,0,0" 
    Header="{x:Static p:Resources.EV_Demandeur}"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushEncadre}" 
    BorderThickness="1" 
    >
    <WrapPanel 
        Margin="0" 
        Orientation="Horizontal" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <TextBlock 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            FontWeight="Normal" 
            Text="text"
            />
    </WrapPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ed Plunkett, It work with GroupBox, even with my style ^^ I don"t know GroupBox before, the only thing i've got to do is to replace my HeaderedContentControl by this. Thanks You ;D

Comment: @StefG Glad to hear it!