# Changing SolidColorBrush#Color in resource dictionary failed: Property is readonly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a `SolidColorBrush` resource in the App.xaml like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="#73AF00" x:Key="BaseGreen"></SolidColorBrush>
```

All my styles(buttons, grid backgroun color, etc, etc) contains that resource and i want that when the user change the color settings, the whole app color will be change to blue.

```
var color = System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources["BaseGreen"] as SolidColorBrush;
                color.Color = Color.FromRgb(41, 128, 185);
```

[I try what this answer suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264222/how-to-change-a-solidcolorbrush-resources-colour-at-runtime) but when I assign the value, an exception is throw:

```
This property is set to read only and cannot be set
```

I also try but nothing happended:

```
var color = this.TryFindResource("BaseGreen") as SolidColorBrush;
color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(41, 128, 185));
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: That would be expected behavior. You should swap resources, not properties. Be that swapping resource dictionaries or other resources within the same one. There's multiple great articles on dynamic theming out there people spent a lot of time on that will explain in better detail.

Answer (score 4):

If you want dynamically set color for your `SolidColorBrush` in `App.xaml`, then you **should not set** the value of color:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DynamicColor" />
</Application.Resources>
```

And in your control you should bind through the `DynamicResource`:

```
    <Label Name="MyLabel" 
           Content="Hello" 
           Background="{DynamicResource Color}" />

    <Button Content="Change color"
            Width="100" 
            Height="30" 
            Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Then to change `Resource` you should:

```
Application.Current.Resources["YourResource"] = YourNewValue;
```

Let me show an example:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush YourBrush = Brushes.Green;

    // Set the value
    Application.Current.Resources["DynamicColor"] = YourBrush;         
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush YourBrush = Brushes.Orange;

    // Set the value
    Application.Current.Resources["DynamicColor"] = YourBrush;
}
```

`DynamicResources` are used for changing. Where to change - this is the wish of the developer.