# WPF: cannot change style SolidColorBrush via code behind because read-only state

Tags: wpf, styles

So inside `Window.Resources` i have this `SolidColorBrush`:

And in separate file (`GridViewColumnHeader.xaml`) i have this `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewHeaderDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Transparent">
                    <TextBlock 
                            x:Name="ContentHeader"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            Padding="0,5,0,0"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            TextAlignment="Left"
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderForegroundColor}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>
```

Now want i try to do is change my `Style` `Foreground` color via code behind:

```
SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush = (SolidColorBrush)this.TryFindResource("GridViewColumnHeaderForegroundColor");
if (solidColorBrush != null)
    solidColorBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
```

But from some reason got this `InvalidOperationException`:

> Additional information: Cannot set a property on object '#FFDCDCDC'
>   because it is in a read-only state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing your Resource Brush, you could define another brush and assign it to the foreground of your style.

However, there is another way of accomplishing your goal.
[Have a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38154421/7277579)

---

First of all you should declare the used style as dynamicresource aswell.

Example:

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="63" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="test" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewHeaderDefaultStyle}" >
            <GridViewColumn Header="header1"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Now you can simply change the Foreground Color by changing the resource brush like that:

```
this.Resources["GridViewColumnHeaderForegroundColor"] = Brushes.Black;
```

Comment: i try Application.Current.Resources["YourResource"] = YourNewValue; and this not effect at all, another issue is that my style is using DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderForegroundColor so if i define another how can i set this new Brush?

Comment: sorry i overread that you defined your styles in Window.Resources. It should work now.